# While running a hive script i am getting container memory limit crossed and failing query. Currently it iset default 1 GB

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am running on a 4 node cluster.

Please suggest what should I put the size of container memory. If I put it more than 1 GB then exactly what size.

What are the criteria for configuring container memory?

**Error:**

> Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
>       Container [pid=46465,containerID=container_1503271937182_4757_01_000032] is
>   running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.0 GB of 1 GB
>   physical memory used; 2.7 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing
>   container.
>       Dump of the process-tree for container_1503271937182_4757_01_000032 :
>               |- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES)
>   FULL_CMD_LINE
>               |- 46465 46463 46465 46465 (bash) 0 0 108654592 308 /bin/bash -c /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java
>   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmx820m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/data3/yarn/nm/usercache/hdfs/appcache/application_1503271937182_4757/container_1503271937182_4757_01_000032/tmp
>   -Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/data1/yarn/container-logs/application_1503271937182_4757/container_1503271937182_4757_01_000032
>   -Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA -Dhadoop.root.logfile=syslog org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild 10.104.72.113 58079 attempt_1503271937182_4757_m_000015_3 32 1>/data1/yarn/container-logs/application_1503271937182_4757/container_1503271937182_4757_01_000032/stdout
>   2>/data1/yarn/container-logs/application_1503271937182_4757/container_1503271937182_4757_01_000032/stderr
>               |- 46483 46465 46465 46465 (java) 2929 1281 2828042240 262018 /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
>   -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmx820m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/data3/yarn/nm/usercache/hdfs/appcache/application_1503271937182_4757/container_1503271937182_4757_01_000032/tmp
>   -Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/data1/yarn/container-logs/application_1503271937182_4757/container_1503271937182_4757_01_000032
>   -Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA -Dhadoop.root.logfile=syslog org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild 10.104.72.113 58079 attempt_1503271937182_4757_m_000015_3 32
>
> Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
>    Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
>
> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
>       MapReduce Jobs Launched:
>       Stage-Stage-1: Map: 18  Reduce: 72   Cumulative CPU: 1219.78 sec   HDFS Read: 3412303867 HDFS Write: 3935714 SUCCESS
>       Stage-Stage-9: Map: 18  Reduce: 72   Cumulative CPU: 332.43 sec   HDFS Read: 3321536722 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
>       Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 25 minutes 52 seconds 210 msec
>       hive failed

Comment: Even I am facing same error. Did you find any solution?